# Ruby roo not finding complex file names

Tags: fileutils

I am using roo to process some Excel files with complex file names (e.g. "Patient Status Up-Date-V2 051812.xlsx"). They are found with proper escaping with OS commands, but not from Ruby roo (which uses fileutils):

```
ls -lt Patient\ Status\ Up-Date-V2\ 051812.xlsx
```

shows:

> -rw-r--r-- 1 hamid hamid 128770 May 22 09:22 Patient Status Up-Date-V2 051812.xlsx

but

```
ruby -rubygems ./findbi.rb Patient\ Status\ Up-Date-V2\ 051812.xlsx
```

gives:

> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/roo-1.10.1/lib/roo/excelx.rb:103:in
>   `initialize': file Patient\ Status\ Up-Date-V2\ 051812.xlsx does not
>   exist (IOError)

I have tried many variations of escaping (on "-" for example), permission changes, run as root, etc to no avail. Line #103 in excelx.rb is line:
raise IOError, "file #{@filename} does not exist"

Please help before I pull out the Perl!

Thanks,
Hamid.